# choose the correct option..?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of  $ G$ such that $H$ is generated by an element $a$ of order $6.$ Let $b ∈ G$.then  $bab^{-1}$  is

Choose the correct option :

$a)$$ a$ or $a^2 $

$b)$$ a$ or $a^3$

$c)$$ a $or $a^4$

$d)$$ a $ or$ a^5$

My attempts  :i   know that$o(a)=o(bab^{-1})=6$. here  i find  none  of the  option is correct,,,but  my professor say me  that  some option is correct...as  im confused   which option is  correct .....

any  hints/ solution will be appreciated.....

Comment: Think about the symmetry group of a regular hexagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to go through the orders of all elements.

Note, that

- the image of the generator $a$ must be a generator
- generators are those $a^k$ with $(k,6)= 1$
- $\Rightarrow o(a) = a$ or $o(a) = a^5$

Comment: +1  superb .......

Answer (score 2):

Since $H$ is cyclic of order 6 and $a$ is a generator, just look at the orders of powers of $a$: $a$ and $a^5$ have order 6; $a^2$ and $a^4$ have order 3; $a^3$ has order 2; and $a^6$ has order 1.  So the answer is $a$ or $a^5$.

Another way to say this is that $|Aut H|=2$ and the non-identity element inverts $a$.